# AngularJS 1.5 Directive to Component migration, calling Page functions from Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, components, angular2-directives

I'm in the process of migrating from AngularJS Directives to Components since upgrading to the 1.5.x version, and in preparation for the 2.0 migration to follow. It's been mostly a smooth transition, but I'm struggling to figure out how to call a function and pass an attribute in my page controller from my component controller.

I have a component defined in my components.js file

```
myApp.component('itemList', {
    bindings: {
        items: '<',
        setCurrentItem: '&'
    },

        templateUrl: 'templates/itemPicker.html',

        controller: function itemPickerController(){

        },

        controllerAs:  'pickerCtrl'

});
```

I have a component template [templates/itemPicker.html]

```
<ul>
    <li class="ng-repeat="item in pickerCtrl.items>
        <button type="button" ng-click="setCurrentItem(item)">
            {{item.name}}
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my page controller [ctrlPage] I have a function:

```
function setCurrentItem(item) {
    ...
}
```

I load the items array from a database, and then display it in my page.html using the component like this:

```
<item-list items="items"></item-list>
```

The repetition displays correctly, however clicking on the button doesn't call the setCurrentItem function in the page, and I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

I've been looking at 'require', and thinking I should be adding this to the component definition,

```
require: '^ctrlPage'
```

But I'm not sure if that's heading in the right direction or not, and what the rest of the syntax would be if that is the right next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template of your ctrlPage you need to hook on the setCurrentItem method of the parent controller, you can do that this way:

`<item-list items="items" set-current-item="ctrlPage.setCurrentItem(item)" ></item-list>`

Also you need to change when you call setCurrentItem and pass him an hash like this:

`<button type="button" ng-click="setCurrentItem({item: item})">`

Comment: Should I be adding require: '^ctrlPage' into the Component definition? If so, is that the right syntax?

Comment: You don't need to require the controller if you use the component bindings and pass the ctrlPage to the setCurrentItem binding.

Comment: It seems like this only works with a component nested inside another component, in my case I'm using routed pages with controllers, and then nesting components in them, and the communication up from the component controller to the page controller doesn't seem to work at all unless the page is a component, and I'm not in a position to start changing the entire application architecture to component just yet, so it seems I'm stuck with Directives for the time being in this instance.

Comment: You can still require external controller from a component this way: 

`.component('myPane', {
  require: {
    tabsCtrl: '^myTabs'
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      this.tabsCtrl.addPane(this);
      console.log(this);
    };
  }
});`

in this case you require the myTabs controller inside the myPane component, just use that in the $onInit function.
Angular need to be of version >= 1.5.3